# Usage of reps in Caliper

Tags: java, performance, hashmap, hashtable, benchmarking

So I read about Caliper and tried to use it. So I wrote the following to start with this framework:

```
   public class HashTableBenchMark  {       
        HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap;

        @BeforeExperiment
        public void setUp() {
            hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        }

        @Benchmark
        public void put(int reps) {
            System.out.println("reps=" + reps);
            for (int i = 0; i < reps; ++i) {
                hashMap.put(i, "" + i);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            CaliperMain.main(HashTableBenchMark.class, args);
        }
    }
```

Should I be setting `reps`? Because it prints always 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't set `reps`, its value is decided internally by Caliper. The only concern handled is the amortization of method invocation overhead and just one rep is actually preferred. Rest assured that your method will be called many more times than just once.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83946/discussion-on-answer-by-marko-topolnik-benchmarking-hashmap-with-caliper-how-to).